# Count all occurrences of a character in a file

Tags: java

I have a file that has text in it, and I am trying to read that file and count how many times each letter in the alphabet occurs and then each letter with its count, I also need to make it case-insensitive.

Any help ? Below is my failed attempt.

```
package assignment6;
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class fileReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/DAndre/Desktop/Alice.txt"));
            int ch;
            char charToSearch='a';
            int counter=0;
            while((ch=reader.read()) != -1) {
                if(charToSearch == (char)ch) {
                    counter++;
                }
            };
            reader.close();

            System.out.println("a occurs " + counter+ " times");



    }

}
```

Comment: Did you look at the `Character` class?

Comment: I would think using a `Bag` collection class would be a more general solution than the character array approach.

Comment: Explain what is not working about what you have so far.  Don't expect people to mentally parse your code or add it to a scratch project to even get started understanding what you are really asking.

Comment: What I am asking is very clear. I want to read in a file and count each occurrence

Comment: But why doesn't it work? Where does it go wrong? This is kind of a required element for questions on StackOverflow, for more info, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Also, if your post gets "put on hold", this is not the end of <strikethrough>the world</strikethrough> your post, it just means you need to add some details or fix some problems with your question by editing it before you can receive more answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an array to hold the counter of the `char`s you're reading. Here's an example:

```
final int charQuantity = 'z' - 'a';
int[] counter = new int[charQuantity];
while ( (ch = reader.read()) >= 0) {
    if (Character.isLetter(ch)) {
        counter[Character.toLowerCase(ch) - 'a']++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not understanding what you are saying

Comment: Imagine you have lot of counters for the letters you look. Once you find a character, then you increase the exact value of the character found. You can take the advantage that `char`s can be widened to `int`s and use the location of the `char` as index (after subtracting `'a'` character).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use a `char` array of size 26 and use `'A'` as an offset (`'A' - 'A' == 0`, `'B' - 'A' == 1`, et cetera). Java's built in `Character` class has a few static methods that should help with case conversion. Then on each letter, you can increment the corresponding array slot.

Comment: I'm not really clear on that

Comment: You're assuming a particular alphabet. His may be very different.

Comment: Using a "`char` array" means the highest number you can count per letter is rather small. It's only a limited set you're counting, no need to stint on the storage space.

Comment: From the question's wording, I don't think it's unreasonable to assume that he's specifically using the Latin alphabet.

Comment: Safe? Ya ñever know.